# Is FIR decimation the fastest possible method for integer downsampling?

Tags: audio, downsampling, decimation

For a digital music synthesizer I am developing, I have a stream of incoming samples $x_i$ and would like to downsample by $M$ to obtain a stream of samples $y_{Mi}$. I am currently bandpassing the signal with an FIR which is a brick-wall filter windowed by Blackman-Harris, and it sounds great to my ears. But I have to compute $y_{Mi} = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} x_{Mi-j} h_j$ for every outgoing sample. $N$ is usually 64 to 256, and $M$ is usually 8 or 16, so an FFT convolution doesn't seem worth it for performance.

If there a better method than naive FIR for integer decimation of audio at these scales? Can I make some reasonable tradeoffs in quality to achieve better performance? For example, polyphase decimation is a nice trick, but since RAM/cache is not an issue, I believe they should run in the same speed since they involve an equal number of multiplications.

Comment: Very good question! Which **architecture** are you working in? Software, hardware, firmware? What about paralellizations? A **polyphase** filter would be **faster** when properly implemented...

Comment: Sure! This software is for desktop operating systems (x86_64 with at least SSE2) using float32s but I'm also interested in answers for ARM Cortex M7 chips like STM32F7s, since I work in that area as well. In both cases, the algorithms will be single threaded. I will look more into polyphase filters to make sure I'm implementing them correctly (I'm probably not.)

Comment: @Fat32 what kind of polyphase filter?

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo the kind? I don't know its kind, but given an FIR impulse response of length L used in a standard decimation by M scheme, you can decompose h[n] into its M polyphase components that're running in **parallel** form. When implemented within parallel hardware (multicore cpu or better the GPU) it will be faster, in contrast to OP's statement in his last paragraph... A single-threaded software implementation, however, is not achieving that benefit.

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks, that answers my question.

Comment: @Fat32 FIRs are also parallelizable in the same way the polyphase filters are, because you can just do a sum reduction. But in my application, this algorithm is one of thousands occurring on a system to produce the final audio stream, and I already parallelize on a higher level, so I don't do algorithm parallelization.

Comment: Just curious; if your application has thousands of them, how do you expect it to run on the STM32F7 (though providing all the befits of a huge horsepower MCU, it falls behind the modern CPU?) I reinsist on the polyphase FIR. It will benefit not only from a reduction in MAC count (compared to an unaware FIR decimator) but it's branches can also run simultaneously and reduce execution **time** (the same  number of MACs completed in less time). There's of course the difficult syncronization issue, but you may give it a try, if you have the time and courage and no other better alternatives...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to design a FIR filter involves matching the impulse response to an analog prototype's impulse response.  The idea being that  an IIR can often be truncated to FIR. The FIR will not be symmetric  and not have linear phase but  the group delay can be much smaller. 
I believe that Friedlander has a paper  on how to do the approximation. There was a Matlab Signal Processing Toolkit function that did this but I haven't had much cause to use it. 
Comet also can do nonsymetric FIR designs.

I also suggest that you try using Parks Mclelan if it can give you a shorter filter than using the window method